# time complexity and size of the input

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm studying for an exam which is mostly about the time complexity. I've encountered a problem while solving these four questions.

1) if we prove that an algorithm has a time complexity of theta(n^2), is it possible that it takes him the time calculation of O(n) for **ALL** inputs?

2) if we prove that an algorithm has a time complexity of theta(n^2), is it possible that it takes him the time calculation of O(n) for **SOME** inputs?

3) if we prove that an algorithm has a time complexity of O(n^2), is it possible that it takes him the time calculation of O(n) for **SOME** inputs?

4) if we prove that an algorithm has a time complexity of O(n^2), is it possible that it takes him the time calculation of O(n) for **ALL** inputs?

can anyone tell me how to answer such questions. I'm mostly confused when they ask for "all" or "some" inputs.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gkovacs90 answer provides a good link : [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

- T(n) = O(n3), means T(n) grows **asymptotically** no faster than n3. A constant `k>0` exists and for all `n>N , T(n) < k*n3`
- T(n) = Θ(n3), means T(n) grows **asymptotically** as fast as n3. Two constants `k1, k2 >0` exist and for all `n>N , k1*n3 < T(n) < k2*n3`

so if `T(n) = n3 + 2*n + 3`

Then `T(n) = Θ(n3)` is more appropriate than `T(n) = O(n3)` since we have more information about the way T(n) behaves asymptotically.

`T(n) = Θ(n3)` means that **for n>N** the curve of T(n) will "approach" and "stay close" to the curve of `k*n3, with k>0`.
`T(n) = O(n3)` means that **for n>N** the curve of T(n) will **always** be under to the curve of `k*n3, with k>0`.

- 1:**No**
- 2:**Yes**, as gkovacs90 says, for small values of `n` you can have O(n) time calculation but I would say **No** for big enough inputs. The notations Theta and Big-O only mean something asymptotically
- 3:**Yes**
- 4:**Yes**

Example for number 4 (dumm but still true) : for an Array A : Int[] compute the sum of the values. Your algorithm certainly will be :

```
Given A an Int Array

sum=0 
for int a in A
    sum = sum + a
end for
return sum
```

If n is the length of the  array A : The time complexity is `T(n) = n`. So `T(n) = O(n2)` since T(n) will not grow faster than n2. And still we have for all array a time calculation of O(n).

If you find such a result for a time (or memory) complexity. Then you can (and certainly you must) refine the Big-O / Theta of your function (here obviously we have :  Θ(n))

Some last points :

- T(n)=Θ(g(n)) implies T(n)=O(g(n)).
- In computational complexity theory, the complexity is sometimes computed for best, worst and average cases.

Comment: Nice answer. I might misunderstood the 4th question. I thought if its time complexity is O(n^2), this means it is not O(n). Algorithms used to be described with the minimal possible complexity, so for question 4: your answer and mine both can be correct. But You're right, of course O(n^2) class contains O(n).

Comment: I agree, a Big-O complexity is useful when it is the minimal possible complexity and it is practically all the time computed this way. But regarding the question and the situation of the OP (exams ...) i think it is more appropriate to stick to the theory.

Answer (score 1):

A "barfoot" explanation:

Big O notation is for setting an upper bound. By definition, there is always an index(or an input-length) from wich the notation is correct. So below this index, anything can happen.

For example sorting an array(`O(n^2)`) with one element takes less time, than writing the elements to the output(`O(n)`). ( we don't sort, we know it is in the right order, so it takes 0 time ).

So the answers:

- 1: No
- 2: Yes
- 3: Yes
- 4: Yes

You can find a detailed understandable description at [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

And [HERE](http://xoax.net/comp_sci/crs/algorithms/lessons/Lesson6/) You can find a simpler explanation.

Comment: um... to tell u the truth, I haven't still understood this.
u said for big O, below the index anything can happen, but for the third question, ur answer is "no". Why?

Comment: Beacause it is for all inputs. All inputs contains the cases above the index too. If the answer would be yes, it would mean that `O(n)=theta(n^2)` which cann't be correct. You cann't just simplify a problem this way to a problem with less time complexity.

Comment: @NavidKoochooloo new link in the post, check it please

Comment: The correct answer to 4 is "yes". Big-O is an upper bound, it doesn't have to be tight.

Comment: @G.Bach Yes, You're right. I've wrote it as a comment to the other answer too. I was confused a litle, because algorithms used to be given with the tightest possible Big-O class.